# Unknown server tag “ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender”

Tags: c#

Unable to add the toolkit script manager into my page. But it is working well in other pages with different master page.

Answer (score 2):

you have remove ajax dll in project file and after build again add.
It's working.

Comment: Thanks Manish now its working. I need one more plus one please make it.

Comment: Thanks@Rahul Kumar